# how to set clickListener to slider layout in daimajia AndroidImageSlider?

Tags: android, clicklistener

I am trying to implement daimajia imageSlider library in my project. Everything else is working perfectly except for the click listener part which is supposed to display a Toast message when slider image is clicked! Is there any way around that I could do this? I have implemented the click listener as:

```
//Setting  click listener
        sliderShow.setOnClickListener(this);

// performing some action here when sliderImage is clicked!
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Util.toast(getActivity(),"image clicked!");
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to show it. Add `.show()` at the end.

Comment: @UmaKanth I have defined a Toast inside static method of Util class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bit late reply but finally I managed to solve the problem . If anybody's facing the similar kind of problem on setting the click listener using this library, I have pasted the code below.You can do the same.

```
 SliderLayout sliderLayout = (SliderLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_slider);
        final List<String> urls = slideImageURLLists();

        for(int i = 0; i<urls.size();i ++){
            DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(mContext);
            final int finalI = i;
            defaultSliderView.image(urls.get(i))
                              .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
                                      Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked image="+urls.get(finalI), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  }
                              });

            sliderLayout.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 textSliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider){

            }
        });
```